# Consider $P(n)$ as a number of $n$-permutations, which each cycle have even length, and ...

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Consider $P(n)$ as a number of $n$-permutations, which each cycle have even length, and $N(n)$ as a number of $n$-permutations, which each cycle have odd length. Calculate $P(2n)-N(2n)$

Comment: Yes, we are considering P(2n) - N(2n) where n is a natural number, and we are considering all types of cycle

Comment: Isn't this the same as was discussed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331504/number-of-permutations-of-a-specific-cycle-decomposition)?

Comment: Yes, it's the same question.