# number of permutations of [n] for which all cycles have even length

Tags: combinatorics, exponential-function, generating-functions

I'm looking to find the number of permutations of [n] for which all cycles have even length, call that number $f_n$.

I've seen here: [Number of permutations of a specific cycle decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331504/number-of-permutations-of-a-specific-cycle-decomposition) that the exponential generating function is given by:

$G_1(z) = 
\exp\left(  \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{z^{2k}}{2k}  \right) =
\sqrt{ \frac{1}{1-z^2}} = \frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{1-z^2}$

Does anyone have an explanation for why we have this egf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally, the exponential generating function for permutations with cycle lengths in some set $S$ is

$$
\exp\left(\sum_{k\in S}\frac{z^k}k\right)\;.
$$

This is because there are $(k-1)!$ different labeled cycles of length $k$, so the exponential generating function for the number of admissible cycles is

$$
\sum_{k\in S}\frac{(k-1)!}{k!}z^k=\sum_{k\in S}\frac{z^k}k\;.
$$

Why going from cycles to permutations consisting of cycles corresponds to exponentiating the exponential generating function is explained at Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_combinatorics#The_multiset.2Fset_operator) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation_statistics#The_fundamental_relation).